# Why does Rust borrow checker ignores the mutable pointer among the function parameters?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, raii

I just got confused by the rust compile error about lifetime.

Suppose the code snippet looks like this:

```rust
fn process(map: &mut HashMap<String, String>, key: String) {
    match map.get_mut(&key) {
        Some(value) => println!("value: {}", value),
        None => {
            map.insert(key, String::new());
        }
    }
}
```

And I called it as follows:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::<String, String>::new();
    let key = String::from("name");
    process(&mut map, key);
}
```

As far as I know(ignore the **NLL** feature), `map.get_mut` returns a `Option<&mut String>` type in which `&mut String` is a borrow pointer which points to part of the map, and the pointer lives through the whole `match` block. Then inside the `None` branch, `map.insert(key, String::new())` creates another `&mut HashMap<String, String>` pointer automatically, which also points to the map. The two pointers borrow the same map as mutable twice, so it causes:

```rust
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*map` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> test.rs:7:13
  |
4 |     match map.get_mut(&key) {
  |           --- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
7 |             map.insert(key, String::new());
  |             ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
8 |         }
9 |     }
  |     - first borrow ends here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

But my question is :

The first parameter of function `fn process` is a mutable pointer itself(`&mut HashMap<String, String>`), which also points to the map. According to the rule above, when the next line calls `map.get_mut(&key)`, the second mutable borrow occurs. Why the compiler doesn't throws a error like this(any risk of memory safe?):

```rust
fn process(map: &mut HashMap<String, String>, key: String)
           --- first mutable borrow occurs here
    match map.get_mut(&key)
    ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here // the return value of type Option<&mut String>
```

I'm newcomer to rust, any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to perform the call to `get_mut`, Rust performs an implicit *reborrow*.

A *reborrow* is equivalent to borrowing from a mutable reference and then flattening the references. That is, given a mutable reference of type `&'a T`, borrowing from it yields a `&'b &'a T` (note that there are two distinct lifetimes; `'b` is shorter than `'a`), and flattening the references yields `&'b T`.

Rust understands that the borrow with lifetime `'b` was derived from the borrow with lifetime `'a`. Thus, borrow `'a` will be frozen for as long as borrow `'b` is alive.

Before NLL, the borrow obtained for the call to `get_mut` would live for the whole `match` block because `get_mut` returns a value that keeps the borrow active. `map.insert(...)` also tries to reborrow from `map`, but since the first reborrow from `map` is still active, that's an error.